# How many years am I banned from entering the Schengen Area?

Tags: schengen, deportation, visa-bans

In 2010, I went to Germany on a business visa that was valid for 7 days. From there, I went to Norway and stayed 1 year and 6 months, working illegally. When the immigration police arrested me, I was using a fake Italian permanent residence card, although I had already applied for asylum in Norway.

After my arrest, I spent 40 days at a detention center in Oslo and was then deported back to my home country, India, on an EU laissez-passer travel document.

Now, it’s almost 5 years since I was deported. I am married, have a 3 year old child, and run my own import-export company in India.  Is it possible to apply for a visa for a family trip? I’m afraid to apply because my biometric records will show this background

Comment: It is very unlikely that you will be granted a visa anymore, considering the graveness of your offence. Moreover, we do not solve individual problems on this site.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being downvoted.  It's a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: The EU has strict data protection laws. Unless you were convicted of a criminal offense, chances are the EU doesn't have biometric information about your past.

Comment: Answering the question in the topic: You're told when you receive a ban, so you're probably not banned - but that doesn't mean you stand any chance of getting in.

Comment: @greatone those laws don't apply to law enforcement.

Comment: It is usual bans for far less severe behaviour last 10 years. Why would you entertain the idea you will ever allowed to come back? It is not even wiser trying and renewing any computer records they might have on you, with luck if you stay way, you *might* get out of records in 10-20 years time. Obviously I might be talking nonsense, but on financial records we have a 10 year retention time frame. Asking in such a short time frame to come back is not good for you.

Comment: @JonathanReez that is why the OP should get a police record before applying. He will know what sort of data they have about him.

Answer (score 5):

You can apply of course, but your chances of success are very probably nil. Your best course of action is to get advice from an immigration lawyer

Comment: https://www.immigrationboards.com/europe-immigration-forum/overstay-and-entry-ban-in-eu-t231888.html

Comment: https://www.immigrationboards.com/europe-immigration-forum/overstay-and-entry-ban-in-eu-t231888.html